# How to point to the relative path of database c# wpf localdb

Tags: c#, wpf, localdb

I trying to make backup and restore as a start i am trying to get backup database so write a code like this

```
try
{
    string cbdfilename = "c:\\Bbcon.bak";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
    string sql = "Backup database @DBNAME to Disk = @FILENAME with Format";
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME", "BbCon");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", cbdfilename);
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Backup DB failed" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

but when i run this code i get an error  database BbCon not exist check your database i don't know what is problem for sure but i think i have given wrong path to database I know the path od database correctly it is like

```
C:\Users\Mahdi Rashidi\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\NOL11TLW.9XG\CZM702AQ.LPP\basu..tion_939730333fb6fcc8_0001.0002_fd707bbb3c97f8d3
```

but this project is for some other clients so when i install this software to other computer path will change so i will get an error so i am begging you all to help finding me a better solution for creating a backup programattically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to create an app.config file and put the backup target path there

OR

What I did some time ago (to load assemblies dynamically, but this piece of code allows u to retrieve the path location based on the assembly that you're running) it was something like:

(Don't forget to add System.Reflection to your using list)

```
// get the current assembly from cache
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

// if current assembly is null
if (currentAssembly == null)
{
    // get the current assembly from stack trace
    currentAssembly = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Last().GetMethod().Module.Assembly;
}

// get the assemblies path (from returned assembly)
assembliesPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentAssembly.Location);
```

From that point now you can concatenate you "Data Path" and save your data there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it helped but now i get another error cannot open backup device i am sorry if i am irritating you by question on question

Comment: second one worked fine.error in the comment rectified by changing the path to c:\users\public

Comment: it's fine, this site objective it's to help each other. Post the full code for deep analysis and, another questions: 1) Are u trying to make the backup on a local machine (where it's running the application)? 2) Are the application and database server running on the same machine? Thank u.

Comment: answer to first question is yes i am trying to make backup an local machine answer to second question is yes database and application is on the same machine database is localdb

Comment: Ok, did u checked the generated string (sql variable) and tried to execute it on SQL Server Management Studio? Is the path that you set dynamically writable (do you have permissions to write on that folder)? A dumb question: does the target folder exists?

Comment: problem solved when string  cbdfilename = "c:\\Bbcon.bak"; changed to string  cbdfilename = "c:\\Users\\Public\\Bbcon.bak"; thanks for your kindness and valuable time